# PYQT6.4 QTableWidget.sortItems function, Pycharm is throwing a syntax issue even though syntax follows documentation

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, pyqt6

Here is the documentation: [QTableWidget.sortItems](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html?highlight=setitem#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.sortItems)

This is the function:

> PySide6.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.sortItems(column[, order=Qt.AscendingOrder])

The following is my code:

`self.notes_current_table_widget.sortItems(column[2, order=Qt.AscendingOrder])`

PyCharm displays this as an error, when I try to run I get:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?
```

Syntax error is in regards to: order=Qt.AscendingOrder

I have tried on other QTableWidgets with the same issue. I have verified that the type is QTableWidget. I have updated all packages to the latest within the project. I have checked syntax of lines before and after.

I ran into this issue because I wanted to sort a dataframe and display the dataframe using a QTableWidget.  df = dataframe. The dataframe is sorted until adding the df to the QTableWidget. That's when I looked at this QTableWidget.sortItems function. Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs say:

> `PySide6.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.sortItems(column[, order=Qt.AscendingOrder])`

The square brackets here indicate that `order` is an *optional* argument, with default value `Qt.AscendingOrder`. You're not supposed to write the square brackets explicitly.

So, your code should probably look like this:

```py
self.notes_current_table_widget.sortItems(column=2, order=Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

Or leave out `order` altogether, as you're using the default value anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know brackets meant it was optional.

Comment: @AndyKrauland It's common in all kinds of [syntax notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirth_syntax_notation).